# Bigquery data transfers from S3 and efficiency of filtering data by last modification datetime

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

I'm planning a pipeline from an S3 bucket to BigQuery. I have set up daily bigquery data transfers from S3 as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer). So, I have a data transfer configuration that looks daily for files with prefix `s3://mybucket/my/path/` and adds them to a BigQuery table.

Now, some of these files are being updated regularly. Fortunately, the data transfer service is smart enough to fetch only new files or updated files.

**My question:** Since S3 does not offer an efficient (i.e. server-side) way to list files by modified datetime, I was wondering how that works. Does google keep track of every PUT event and keeps the metadata somewhere, including modification time, so they know which files to transfer at the next transfer run?

**Why I'm asking this:** the bucket is going to get huge sooner or later, a lot of the files in there are going to be updated regularly (i.e. same key, but the content will change), so I want to know if each data transfer run will have to scan the whole bucket!

Of course I'm sure Google's engineers would implement the best possible solution, I don't doubt that, but I would like to make sure this won't be a bottleneck along the way.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary y You're right. Maybe the question could be formulated better, and ask instead the experience of people who used date transfer on heavily populated buckets of regularly updated files..

Comment: Hi @geo909, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduled transfers use modification time filtering to avoid transferring duplicate data. In terms of the performance, the main bottleneck would be global S3 to GCP bandwidth limitations which is hard to predict and varies a lot between regions, but it's generally in the x10Gbps scale.

BigQuery data transfer service is generally recommended for structured <15 TB data. Very generic network transfer time estimates is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/transfer-appliance/docs/4.0/overview).

You  should also consider the relevant [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/quotas#transferOperations) for transfer operations.

While TLS is used in data transfer, if you would like to do data transfers over secure private connections, you should  consider using [VPC-SC](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/transferring-data-from-amazon-s3-to-cloud-storage-using-vpc-service-controls-and-storage-transfer-service).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still curious though.. Modification time filtering is performed on the client side. In other words, all the files should be scanned in order to obtain the modification dates and then filter. So, is that what happens in every data transfer indeed?

Comment: Yes, the files will be scanned in order to obtain the modification dates and then filter in data transfer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a source on that, or is that an educated guess?